# Global Semaphore ignores local Semaphore

Tags: windows, delphi, semaphore

I have an application that accesses some files and system ressources, so there may only be one instance of the application active. That is accomplished by creating a named Semaphore and stopping the applicationrun when the Semaphore is already assigned.
In the past (read: when Windows XP was the most common Operating System) that worked well, but now we noticed that the old code did not work with multiple user sessions.

Here the old code:

```
hInstanceSem := CreateSemaphore(nil, 0, 1, PChar(GetProductName(Application.ExeName)));
if (hInstanceSem <> 0) and (GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) then
// do not run the Application
```

So I did some research, learned about global Semaphores and changed the code to this:

```
function CreateGlobalSemaphor(SemaphorName: String): Cardinal;
var
  desc: SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
  att : TSecurityAttributes;
  sem : Cardinal;
begin
  att.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
  att.bInheritHandle := true;
  att.lpSecurityDescriptor := @desc;

  InitializeSecurityDescriptor(att.lpSecurityDescriptor, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
  SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(att.lpSecurityDescriptor, True, nil, False);

  sem := CreateSemaphore(@att, 0, 1, PChar('Global\' + SemaphorName));
  if (sem <> 0) and (GetLastError() <> ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) then begin
    Result := sem;
  end else begin
    Result := 0;
    CloseHandle(sem);
  end;
end;

if CreateGlobalSemaphor(GetProductName(Application.ExeName)) = 0 then
// do not run the Application
```

Now, when I start the application on User1, change to User2 and try starting the Application, it will not run (as intended).

BUT when I run an older version of my program and start the current version with the new code in the same user session, the new code ignores the Semaphore created by the older code and a second instance of my application is started. (Needless to say that it crashes...)

It seems to me that the local Semaphore is out of the scope of the global Semaphore, else a second object with the same name could not be created.
My question is: How can the global Semaphore (new code) detect, that a local Semaphore (old code) with the same name is already assigned?

Please keep in mind that this is a problem of backward compatibility. I cannot simply recompile and redistribute the older versions of my application.

Comment: Let me guess, that `GetLastError` function call returns 5 (`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`). No, seriously, what does it return ?

Comment: Why don't you *try* and create a local semaphore (via old code) in your new code, and check for result first, before you handle the global semaphore?

Comment: @TLama: `GetLastError` returns 0 (NO_ERROR)

Comment: You have a resource leak. If `CreateSemaphore` succeeds, and the semaphore already existed, then `Result` holds a handle to that semaphore. If you don't want that handle, then you need to close it. Merely overwriting `Result` with zero causes that handle to leak.

Comment: Note that Windows XP supported the global namespace and multiple sessions, too — the feature is called "fast user switching" — so it's not really correct to say that your previous code "worked well." It's just that you're a little over a decade late to realize your mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for [kernel object namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa382954.aspx) explains that:

> For processes started under a client session, the system uses the session namespace by default.

Since the old program does not explicitly include a namespace, the session namespace, `Local\` is used. This means that the old program creates a semaphore named `Local\xxx`. Now, the new program uses a semaphore named `Global\xxx`. So you have two distinct semaphores and the programs are completely unaware of themselves.

- If you want the new program to interact with the old program, you must use an object named `Local\xxx`.
- If you wish the new program to block other new programs in different sessions, you must use an object named `Global\xxx`.

The obvious conclusion to draw here is that you need to create two objects. One named `Local\xxx` and one named `Global\xxx`.

Note that it is not possible to backfit cross-session exclusion to the existing programs. They already use `Local\xxx` and there's no way to you to change that now.

You must also fix the error handling in your new code. You call `CreateSemaphore` and then go on to call `GetLastError` without first checking the value returned by the call to `CreateSemaphore`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was so caught up in my thoughts that I did not see the simple sollution - to create two Semaphores with the same name

Comment: Well, same name, different namespace prefix